# htaccess para web.config

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, iis, web.config

Mudei o meu site para a plataforma [Windows Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/) e o servidor deles é **IIS** e o meu antigo era apache então as rotas configuradas no **htaccess** não estão funcionando, preciso saber como faço para converter isto:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

php_value short_open_tag off

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meusite\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.meusite\.com\.br$
```

Em **web.config(parecido com xml)** para funcionar no **IIS**

Comment: Você pode usar um covnersor online para testar: [Link](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx)

Comment: Legal, mas ele converte apenas o `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A conversão pelo [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) (você pode instalar no seu [IIS](http://www.iis.net/home) local e gere a saída pelo arquivo `.htaccess`) fica em um arquivo [web.config](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815179/pt-br) dessa forma, baseado no seu `.htaccess` da questão:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Nesse **[*link*](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)** também possui vários estilos de arquivos (`.htaccess`), que você pode se basear para que seu sistema funcione no seu [IIS](http://www.iis.net/home) do [Windows Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/) e nesse [link](http://www.saotn.org/convert-apache-htaccess-iis-web-config-part2-iis-manager-import/#.U62TEvldXz4) um outro exemplo prático do assunto.

*Referências:*

- [IIS HOME](http://www.iis.net/home)
- [Translate .htaccess Content to IIS web.config](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)
- [Microsoft Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/)

Comment: Nossa deu certo, valeu! eu até tinha conseguido de uma forma parecida mas estava dando erro na hora de encontrar os arquivos css e imagens, mas do seu jeito deu certo!

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha legal ... !!! :)